# "apache2.service is not active, cannot reload." Cannot figure out the error cause! Any advice greatly appreciated

Tags: apache2, wordpress

I have tried to setup Wordpress via an Apache2 webhost on an Amazon EC2 instance. The setup went fine until i tried to start the apache server and the response was:
`apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.`

Below is the output from `sudo service apache2 status`

[link to the status output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18C9p.png)

I'm very new when it comes to servers and system architectures! Thanks in advance for your time and any help or guidance you can provide.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Address already in use ... Apache is already running, or something else is using port 80 (or what port you have configured apache to use).